How to Render GStreamer Video Stream to a WPF Element (e.g., Image) Using AppSink?
I am using C# (.NET 7) and GStreamer to handle an RTSP stream and render the video to a WPF Image element. I aim to use appsink to process the video frames. Below is the pipeline definition I am using:
string pipelineDescription = $"rtspsrc location={rtspUrl} ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! appsink name=mysink";
The pipeline initializes successfully, and when I list the elements using ListPipelineElements, I can see that mysink exists. However, when I attempt to retrieve the mysink element using GetChildByName("mysink") or manually iterate through the pipeline elements with IterateElements, the mysink element is recognized as a generic Element and not an AppSink. This results in the following error during type casting:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Gst.Element' to type 'Gst.App.AppSink'
I used the following method to list pipeline elements:
private void ListPipelineElements(Pipeline pipeline)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pipeline elements:");
    foreach (var obj in pipeline.IterateElements())
    {
        if (obj is Element element)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($" - Element Name: {element.Name}, Type: {element.GetType().Name}");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unknown element type found.");
        }
    }
}

Output:
Pipeline initialized successfully.
Pipeline elements:

Element Name: capsfilter0, Type: Element
Element Name: mysink, Type: Element
Element Name: videoconvert0, Type: Element
Element Name: decodebin0, Type: Bin
Element Name: rtspsrc0, Type: Bin
Checked element: capsfilter0
Checked element: mysink
Element 'mysink' is not an AppSink, type: Element
Checked element: videoconvert0
Checked element: decodebin0
Checked element: rtspsrc0
Could not find 'mysink' as an AppSink in the pipeline.

Attempts:

Retrieving Element from Pipeline:


Used GetChildByName("mysink"), but it was detected as a generic Element.


Listing Pipeline Elements:


Used IterateElements() to manually list pipeline elements and confirmed that mysink was present but detected as Element.


Type Casting:


Attempted to cast the element manually:
var appSink = (AppSink)sinkElement;
Resulted in:
System.InvalidCastException


Manual Pipeline Creation:


Manually created and added AppSink to the pipeline:

var appSink = new AppSink("mysink");
_pipeline.Add(appSink);

While this allowed defining the element, dynamic linking within the pipeline failed.

Basic Pipeline Testing:


Tested a simpler pipeline with videotestsrc:
string pipelineDescription = "videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! appsink name=mysink";
Faced the same type casting issue with AppSink.


Rendering Video to WPF Image:


Attempted to update the Image control with GStreamer frame data:

private void UpdateBGImage(int width, int height, IntPtr data)
{
    int size = width * height * 4;
    int stride = ((width * 32 + 31) & ~31) / 8;

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, data, size, stride);
        BGImage.Source = source;
        this.InvalidateVisual();
    });
}

However, the Image control did not update.
What I Expected:

Successfully retrieve the mysink element as an AppSink.

Process frames using AppSink and update a WPF Image control.


What Happened:

mysink was detected as a generic Element.

Type casting to AppSink failed.


Additional Information and Attempts:

Alternative Binding Libraries:


Tested gstream-sharp and gstream-sharp-core without success.
Attempted to reference gstapp-1.0-0.dll, but received "invalid reference" errors.


Working Example with Windows Forms:
The following pipeline worked in a Windows Forms project:
rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/mystream latency=300 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
However, I need this to work in WPF with .NET 7.

My Questions:

How can I retrieve the AppSink element from a GStreamer pipeline in C#?
Is there a compatibility issue with the libraries or binding? If so, what is the recommended GStreamer binding for .NET 7?
How can I efficiently render GStreamer video streams to a WPF Image element?


From what I can tell you need to use a VideoOverlayAdapter. You might find some useful information on this GitHub

Did you try qoutes arround the name='mysink'

@CharlesHenington I tried the WPF code from this GitHub repository. In the code, I selected a video from a specific file and played it on the VideoPanel while placing a button on top. However, the button stayed behind the video. What I want is for the button and textboxes to appear in front of the video, with the video staying behind the UI elements.
It didn't help completely but it might work partially, I'm trying it right now.

@Christoph Yes, I tried the code as follows:
        pipeline = (Pipeline)Parse.Launch(
            $"rtspsrc ... ! appsink name='mysink'"
        );
        var appSink = (AppSink)pipeline.GetChildByName("mysink");
        appSink.EmitSignals = false;
        pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);

However, I encountered an error at the line appSink.EmitSignals = false; and it said:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
appSink was null.
Where am I going wrong?

I tried manually creating AppSink elements one by one and checked after each line (I didn’t write the entire code). Here's an example:
// Manually create the pipeline
pipeline = new Pipeline("video_pipeline");
.............
var appsink = ElementFactory.Make("appsink", "mysink") as AppSink;
if (appsink == null) throw new Exception("The AppSink element (appsink) could not be created!");
I received the error: "The AppSink element (appsink) could not be created!"
